# Category archive page redirects to home page

Tags: categories, archives

I have a multisite setup, any attempt to load /category/news or suchlike simply redirects to the home page. This is true for all categories.

in the case of the main sub-site it appends /wordpress (even though the main site domain does not include /wordpress so in this instance it returns a 404

In the case of the other subsites, it redirects to the home page.

There is nothing in the htaccess that explains this and I have flushed the rewrite rules

I have tried setting permalinks to default so I have /?cat=123 and this also redirects to the home page

archive.php exists.

Any suggestions or trouble shooting process gratefully received.

As a corollary to this it would be very useful to be able to track any redirects.  So that I can see the process by which https://example.com/category/news redirects to https://example.com  but I can't find anything that does this.

Comment: Since this isn't default WordPress behaviour I'd suggest switching to a standard theme and then disabling plugins one by one until the problem goes away.

Comment: It's not a plugin issue as such, using TwentyTwenty the category page appears as it should. What could be in our custom theme that stops it working?

Comment: But thank you, you've got me thinking in the right direction. If it's in the theme it can't be a Wordpress issue.